# Show y*x=0 by eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be two distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

If $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, $y^∗$ is a nonzero row vector such that $y^∗ (A − \mu I) = 0$, show that $y^∗ x = 0$.

can someone give me some direction to solve this problem?

Comment: "Can I simply prove it by letting a square matrix?" ... letting a square matrix *WHAT*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume I is the identity matrix. Since y*(A−μI)=0 then distributing yields y$^*A$=y$^*μI$ , since x is a eigen vector we have y$^*$Ax-y$^*$μIx=0$
so you need to know the fact that if you have a matrix A and a vector v such that Av=0 then A=0 or v=0.

Comment: ok thanks! i will try to approach in this way

Comment: No problem, if my answer was helpful I would appreciate it if you click on the check mark

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the property that 
$$y^*(Ax)=(y^*A)x.$$

Answer (score 0):

We may as well start with $y^*(A-\mu I) = 0$ and see what happens:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= y^*(A - \mu I)\\
  &= y^*(A - \mu I)x\\
  &= y^*(Ax - \mu x)\\
  &= \ldots
\end{align*}
$$
... can you take it from here?

---

**spoiler alert**

> $$0 = y^*(Ax - \mu x) = y^*(\lambda x - \mu x) = y^*x(\lambda - \mu)$$ and as $\lambda \neq \mu$ we must have $y^*x = 0$.

Comment: so we get y*=0, x=0 or (A-μ)=0?